# Python, Pandas dataframe, merge dataframe's rows that have same two column values and aggregate data in rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this DF and I am trying to merge any two rows with similar `workDate` and `ID`. I do not know how many columns this DF will have. it might have hundreds of columns so I am looking for a way to merge without having to specify all column names

```
    |workDate   |ID       | Hours |Groundsman  |names2  |Teachers       |Profs
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   |2020-01-09 |13702    | 1.0   |   Ted      |        |               |
1   |2020-01-09 |13702    | 1.0   |            |Seline  |               |
2   |2020-01-10 |13702    | 20.0  |            |Ted,Sam |               |
3   |2020-01-10 |13702    | 20.0  |            |        |Pete,Norm,Tim  |
4   |2020-01-10 |13702    | 20.0  |            |        |               |Joe
```

Desired output:

```
    |workDate   |ID       | Hours |Groundsman  |names2  |Teachers       |Profs
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   |2020-01-09 |13702    | 1.0   |   Ted      |Seline  |               |
1   |2020-01-10 |13702    | 20.0  |            |Ted,Sam |Pete,Norm,Tim  |Joe
```

I have tried multiple ways of grouping by but non of got me the desired output. As I mentioned DF might have a lot of other columns so I can not use a solution that expects all columns names to be included.
it's basically group by `workDate` and `ID` but I also want to keep all values in other columns

Comment: It's not very clear what your logic is. How do you determine which value to keep for similar `workDate` and `ID` ?

Comment: it's basically group by `workDate` and `ID` but I also want to keep all values in other columns. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I edited the output. maybe that was confusing. the first column that has 0 and 1 is just the index column and I do not care about it

Comment: In your example: what if - rather than hours=1 and hours=1 for the first and second rows, you saw hours=1 and hours=5? Which value would be kept for that group?

Comment: @Reinderien if `workDate` and `ID` match then `hours` will be matching as well.

Comment: That's not quite good enough - defensive programming needs to assume that if something bad may happen, it will. The answer from @MDR takes the last value seen, which is maybe fine for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np #only required because the example df creation needs np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'workDate': {0: '2020-01-09',
  1: '2020-01-09',
  2: '2020-01-10',
  3: '2020-01-10',
  4: '2020-01-10'},
 'ID': {0: 13702, 1: 13702, 2: 13702, 3: 13702, 4: 13702},
 ' Hours': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 20.0, 3: 20.0, 4: 20.0},
 'Groundsman': {0: '   Ted', 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan},
 'names2': {0: np.nan, 1: 'Seline', 2: 'Ted,Sam', 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan},
 'Teachers': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: 'Pete,Norm,Tim', 4: np.nan},
 'Profs': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: 'Joe'}})

print(df.groupby(by=['workDate', 'ID']).last().reset_index())
```

**Outputs:**

```
     workDate     ID   Hours Groundsman   names2       Teachers Profs
0  2020-01-09  13702     1.0        Ted   Seline           None  None
1  2020-01-10  13702    20.0       None  Ted,Sam  Pete,Norm,Tim   Joe
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this seems that it should work but does it require/expect the empty cells in the initial DF to have `nan` or `None` values to work?

Comment: Answering myself, Yes,  I replaced empty cells with `nan` and this has worked for me. Thanks!!